# How to remove old metal shower drain?

Tags: shower, drain, pipe

I have this shower drain piece from 1970s, and can't budge at all.

Is there any smarter way to remove this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The lower half of that assembly is connected to the sewer pipe (by one of several possible means) and the upper part was/is threaded into the lower part. These were originally designed to give the installer an adjustable height, to accommodate the finished thickness of the dry-packed cement tile base. Is it your intention to remove the whole assembly? If so, you will need to break up the concrete floor to remove it from the sewer pipe.

Comment: `Is there any smarter way to remove this?` .... smarter than what? .... you made no mention of your attempt

Comment: it is unclear in the picture, but it almost looks like left handed thread

Comment: might try gently heating the bottom with a blowtorch while having a icepack on the top...

Comment: @dandavis That probably will not work in this situation just personal experience. I hope that he has no sewer gas while heating with the blow torch.

Comment: @jsotola - these are right hand thread. Standard Drain pipes. I know his picture angle makes it look deceiving..but they are right hand threads. Just 40 years and the two metals cold and hot with moisture have 'welded' together. I actually have experienced ops situation 1970's home as well.

Comment: Thanks guys! Ouch, my cousin was trying to work on this, but he snapped the whole thing, and the top part came out of the lower part.

Comment: @jsotola I meant to say, any tips and tricks, because I was using a pipe wrench to remove the top part. But, now, I got top part, lower half, down spout/pipe and the hole on the floor. :(

Comment: do not throw out the part you removed ... use it for checking the fit of a new pipe .... maybe you can find pipe that fits tightly inside the broken pipe section

Comment: He is gonna cut the concrete around it, dig the ground to reveal the sewer line, replace the trap there. Does it sounds like a good plan?

Comment: Whole top assembly https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HMaEh7n96YygBWDqsVTaiGcvyyXg18L6

Comment: The hole https://drive.google.com/open?id=18NT4ly7LVG1Qznbln0vIyIPTHWGKj4b9

Comment: Part where it came off from the ground https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GW38m_uTYC4DA3b_T7mHn1fQE2-rp6mi

Answer (score 1):

The lower part is your actually sewer pipe connection - you should not remove this unless you are looking to do a lot more work.

I have had your exact issue. Here is what you need to do to remove the upper threaded unit (the drain that fits the shower) . Remove the screen so you have access to the inner part of the drain pipe. Now you can use a hacksaw blade , a dremel tool, a small cutoff wheel to cut into the drain pipe - do not cut into your threads but get close enough.

Now you will want to place a rag down the pipe - something you can retrieve - tie a string to it if need be .. in case pieces fall.

At this point you should be able to bend in the pipe using a hammer with an iron bar or iron chisel .. breaking the "seal" it has to the threads at this point you can lubricate around the unit with WD40 and wait a few moments - you might be able to unscrew it or you might need to tap on it in a CCW direction with that chisel to budge it in order to get it to to unscrew. If it still will not budge - you might need to do another slice down the length of the drain pipe and attempt the same thing of course at this point the whole unit might bend in enough to allow you to simply pull it out. The latter was what I ended up doing as mine turned a little bit and then still stuck - so instead pf playing around I did 1/3 the way to the other side and chisel bent the remaining piece and the whole thing came out nicely. I cleaned the threads with plenty of WD40 and a wire brush so I could install the new drain.

Any questions just ask.

Comment: I wish I was able to see your answer before let my cousin touch the top part with a big pipe wrench. He pulled the whole thing off with the lower part and the down pipe. Ouch...

Comment: @Nomadme ouch is right - now your job is much more difficult and expensive - you will be pulling up concrete. I admit it took me a while to figure out how to get mine out - I was really not wanting to dig any concrete - saw videos about that lower pipe being replaced. Good luck to in taking care of it. Now I wish I tagged you in the comment you made on another post - I thought about it but got distracted.

Comment: @GanbayarGansukh it's always a good idea to submit your result with pictures so we can see what yours looked like when you removed it and what made it more costly. I'm not sure when you said he removed the drain pipe what you mean... The lower part i'm guessing goes into the drain pipe? how did it remove the drain pipe too?

Comment: @EvanCarroll the op did post pictures. You have two parts of the drain system. The spud fitting - the piece your drain cover mounts to, you might also have a spud extender which allows the drain height to be set. Damaging anything lower then the spud fitting / spud extender will cost you plenty of time and money. Obviously I had performed my work before the op or I would have posted pictures if I had been inclined to make a post. You might get away with an oscillating tool - but be VERY careful what piece you cut. I cut vertically. to split the piece off the threads.